# Create External Table Error while converting VARCHAR to Datetime and VARCHAR to Decimal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I tried to create an external table from CSV file(which is in cloud storage), I'm getting error in converting Varchar to datetime and Varchar to decimal. Can someone please help me in this whats going wrong

Error messages

> HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: HadoopSqlException: Error converting data type VARCHAR to DECIMAL.

[image: Data screenshot]

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [ext].[Load_History_test]
(   [Table_Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Loaded_On] [datetime] NULL,
    [Transferred_Count] [decimal](30) NULL,
    [Transferred_Volume_MB] [decimal](30) NULL,
    [Load Duration] [time] NULL,
    [Throughput_Records] [decimal](30) NULL,
    [Throughput_Volume_KB_sec)] [decimal](30) NULL
)
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = [ADLS_External_Landing],LOCATION = N'/refdata/replicate/load_history',FILE_FORMAT = [CSVFileFormatwithHeaderloadhistory],REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,REJECT_VALUE = 0)
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [CSVFileFormatwithHeaderloadhistory] WITH (FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT, FORMAT_OPTIONS (FIELD_TERMINATOR = N',',

STRING_DELIMITER = N'0x22',
DATE_FORMAT = N'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 
FIRST_ROW = 2,
USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = FALSE))
GO
```

Comment: Are you sure all of the dates are in `d/m/y`? Are you sure none of the rows have invalid dates or invalid decimals or too many commas or ... note that the row(s) causing the problem might not conveniently be among the three rows captured in your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, yeah there was few rows not appropriate format. Fixing that fixed whole issue thanks

Comment: @user2703679, people check the thread and waste time since you already found the solution. Maybe Aaron can write his comment as answer you you should in order to mark an answer to close the thread

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one date not in `d/m/y` format, one decimal too large, or one or more rows have too many or too few commas causing invalid formats.

Note that the row(s) causing the problem might not conveniently be among the three rows captured in your screenshot.